# How Do I Disable Windows 7 Accessibility Apps?

Tags: windows-7

I want to permanently disable or remove Magnifier, Narrator, On-Screen Keyboard and High Contrast or at least permanently disable their keyboard shortcuts. I'm using Win7 inside a Parallels VM with an old IBM keyboard (SpaceSaver II) and USB/PS2 adaptor. Despite all my best efforts to customise the keyboard for the VM, the accessibility shortcuts activate almost by themselves at critical times :-(

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can we assume you have trawled through the "Ease of Access" control panel to disable all of these features?

Comment: I pretty much had, with the exception of the (less intuitive) ones under 'Make Keyboard Easier to Use' as per @Kyle 's post.

Comment: I wasn't needing this for the VM solution, but the answer provided saved me a ton of headache.

Comment: I dont know how this is happening, but any time my baby's hands reach the computer, the accessibility features get enabled :) After that the computer keeps reading loud anything i do or write to the screen, which of course is not helping it sleep either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for the shortcut keys you were talking about and found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449). So I assume you are talking about filter keys? If so browse to 'Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use' there is options for turning filter keys off. As Tog said all the settings seem to revolve around the "Ease of Access center". If you want to see all options available in windows 7 create a new folder and rename it: 
Options.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C} The part before the "." (period) can be what ever you want I just figured "options" or settings makes sense.

Comment: Looking good, I had forgotten all about 'God Mode' ...

I will mark your answer as 'Accepted' if, in five days time, I haven't had to look at the retro travesty that is Windows Magnifier ;-)

Comment: haha, I went in there just to look at the options when I was answering this and the stupid narrator auto-started and began announcing what I was looking at to the whole office... I hate the accessibility options I wish we could just uninstall them with add/remove like in xp.

Comment: It would be nice if some of the settings available in here were just in the control panel like I would have expected.  Solved my problem in about 30 seconds once I tried this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the tools on a per-user basis, or for all users. You just need modify the access-rights for the programs in the **C:\Windows\System32** folder.

- **Magnify.exe**
- **Narrator.exe**
- **Osk.exe**

To prevent a user from executing a file:

1. Make yourself owner of the file.

   1. Open **Properties** dialog for the file.
   2. Select the **Security** tab.
   3. Click the **Advanced** button.
   4. Select the **Owner** tab.
   5. Click the **Edit** button.
   6. Select yourself in the list.
   7. Click the **OK** button.
   8. Close all the dialogs. (To update for the new owner)
2. Make the user unable to execute the file.

   1. Open **Properties** dialogs for the file.
   2. Select the **Security** tab.
   3. Click the **Advanced** button.
   4. Select the **Permissions** tab. (Default)
   5. Click the **Change permissions** button.
   6. Click the **Add** button.
   7. Type the username, or find by clicking the **Advanced** button.

      - Alternatively, you could add **Users** for to disable them for everybody.
   8. On the row **Traverse folder / execute file** and row **Deny**, check the check-box.
   9. Click the **OK** button.
   10. Close all dialogs.

Now the keyboard-shortcuts won't do anything. At least not anything visible.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize your W7 installation disc, remove the component completely

http://www.rt7lite.com/

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I want to do a full reinstall just to fix this issue though. Annoying though it is.

Comment: I'll give him a +1 since this is the method for getting rid of the component completely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have accidentally turned on the 'Sticky Keys' feature of Windows 7, which messes with some of the modifier keys like the Windows Key. Press both SHIFT keys simultaneously to turn it off, maybe this helps.